# determine docker entrypoint of compressed/ flattened image

Tags: docker

I am using a Binami Keycloak image from Docker Hub.

Where dockerhub usually shows the individual layers of the image I am only seeing one Layer for this image [bitnami/keycloak:22.0.4](https://hub.docker.com/layers/bitnami/keycloak/22.0.4/images/sha256-49acd4ef67bdfda635a56c4c21ab6b4fddc9929679ce579b684f3d0359902107?context=explore):

```
crane flatten sha256:e78d228bddb78d9e26cebddbf17f3b0eab48078237f07d5b3e643d1b5658db5f
```

`crane` seems to be a command line tool that is able to flatten docker images ([crane flatten docs](https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/blob/main/cmd/crane/doc/crane_flatten.md)).

How can I determine the entrypoint command of the flattened image ? And what user is used in the image?

I was able to use the tool [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) to look at the files contained in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the information from `docker inspect bitnami/keycloak:22.0.4`.

To extract the cmd, entrypoint and user values from the inspect output using `jq`, you can do

```
docker inspect bitnami/keycloak:22.0.4 | jq -r '.[0].Config.Cmd[0]'
docker inspect bitnami/keycloak:22.0.4 | jq -r '.[0].Config.Entrypoint[0]'
docker inspect bitnami/keycloak:22.0.4 | jq -r '.[0].Config.User'
```

If you're better at `jq` than I am, you can probably extract all 3 fields in one go :)